# How should I implement a reusable component on a .net Core Razor pages app that can handle a form submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to implement a ViewComponent that includes a form with a submit button. Upon clicking the button, the form is submitted and a record is added to the database along with returning a success message. This is all done asynchronously so I simply return a status to the current razor page being viewed.

I want to embed this form/functionality across many pages in my application so that is why im looking at a ViewComponent. I dont want to have to implement the same OnPost functionality for every Razor Page that I add this form to.

If that makes any sense?

Here's how I show the form on a razor page.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("QuoteForm", new Models.Quote())
```

Here's my simple invoke method.

```
//Show a ViewComponent with form
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
   Quote quote = new Quote();

   //Return View with ViewModel from below.
   return View("QuoteFormView", quote);
}
```

Can I do something like this with a ViewComponent?

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> OnPostAsync(Quote quote)
{
    //Model did not pass validation.
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else 
    {
        //Do database work and send email

        //return status to view.
        return Content("Database updated and Email Sent.");
    }
}
```

Comment: "I dont want to have to implement the same OnPost functionality": You don't have to. One `OnPost` method should work for all the places where you add the view component.

Comment: If you mean to use one `OnPost` across different Apps, consider creating a Razor Component Library instead.

Comment: I am using .net core Razor pages. So if I embed the ViewComponent on my "index" page and also my "about us" page....Where would the post event code be located? Would it be in the ViewComponent class? The Index pagemodel class, or the about us pagemodel class. It appears that ViewComponent can not handle http requests.

Comment: 1. The `OnPost` handler should be put in a **Razor Page** or a **Controller Action**. You can never put in into a `ViewComponent` class. `ViewComponent` is designed to deal with view instead of dealing HTTP Requests. 2. My best guess is: you want a [RCL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). Just put your controller/pages and your ViewComponent into a separated RCL project, and reference that project so that you don't need create OnPost event handler code anymore.